# Синхронная прокрутка двух ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Имеется два `ViewPager`. Они имеют разную ширину. Второй `ViewPager` должнен пролистываться только тогда, когда первый пролистывается. 
Одновременное пролистывание сделать получилось, но кода оно завершается, то у второго `ViewPager` возвращается контент первого слайда.

```
firstViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(final int position, final float positionOffset, final int positionOffsetPixels)
            {
                secondViewPager.scrollTo((int) (positionOffsetPixels * scale), 0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(final int position)
            {}

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(final int state)
            {}
        });
```

Может есть другой способ это сделать?

[image]

Нашел вот такой вот вариант. Но если начать перемещать влево, а потом, не отпуская пальца, вправо, то у `secondViewPager` страница сразу же меняется на следующую. Попытка исправить ни к чему не привела

```
firstViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()
{
    private int mLastScrollPosition;
    private int mLastPagePosition;
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(final int position, final float positionOffset, final int positionOffsetPixels)
    {    
        if (secondViewPager.isFakeDragging())
        {
            final int scaledPositionOffsetPixels = (int) (positionOffsetPixels * scale);
            int absoluteOffsetPixels = scaledPositionOffsetPixels;
            if (mLastPagePosition != position)
            {   
                absoluteOffsetPixels += (position - mLastPagePosition) * secondViewPager.getWidth();                
                mLastPagePosition = position;            
            }
            secondViewPager.fakeDragBy((mLastScrollPosition - absoluteOffsetPixels));
            mLastScrollPosition = scaledPositionOffsetPixels;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(final int position) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(final int state)
    {
        switch (state)
        {
            case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING:
                if (!secondViewPager.isFakeDragging())
                    secondViewPager.beginFakeDrag();
                break;
            case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING:
            case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
                if (secondViewPager.isFakeDragging())
                {
                    secondViewPager.endFakeDrag();
                    mLastScrollPosition = 0;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

**Обновление**

Пришлось отказаться от этой идеи и делать один `ViewPager`. Жаль, выглядело бы красиво

Comment: Возможно, я не совсем верно вас понял, но если два `ViewPager`'а пролистываются только совместно, почему бы не сделать это одним `ViewPager`?

Comment: @falstaf потому что они должны быть разной ширины. На контенте такого эффекта не получить.

Comment: а почему не добавили в onPageSelected аналогичный код по выбору страницы во втором пейджере?

Comment: @metalurgus потому что прокрутка нужна только по первому, второй касания не обрабатывает

Comment: @Andreich но страницы-то он должен переключать вместе с первым?

Comment: `@Override
        public void onPageSelected(final int position)
        {
            secondPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        }`

Comment: @metalurgus он будет просто менять страницу с задержкой, мне надо чтобы они прям скролились синхронно

Answer (score 1):

Единственный вариант решения, который приходит в голову — это попробовать написать свою `View`. `View` будет состоять из двух частей: верхняя, уменьшенная и вторая — увеличенная. На первой будет стоять `MotionEventListener`, который будет реагировать на касания и при каждом "пролистаном" пикселе будет пролистывать содержание второй части на 4 пикселя (множитель увеличения будет варьироваться в зависимости от зума второй части).

Свое изучение написания кастомных `View` следует начать от сюда — [ссылка](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html).

---

Но, мне кажется, что стоит еще раз подумать над тем, зачем это делать. Может будет достаточно увеличения текста или растяжения изображения?

Answer (score 0):

а почему ты не можешь сделать один viewpager. в этот viewpager закидываешь основной лэйаут(что то типа linear vetical), а уже в него две вьюшки разной ширины. вроде бы должно быть как на картинке, прост фон у главной вьюшки не указывай.